# How do I get the time it takes to travel between two points in a circular motion?

Tags: geometry, physics

I have two points on a circle.

[Circle with two points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMuqh.png)

Given that I have the constant angular velocity, cartesian coordinates of the two points and center, and the radius. How would I get the time it would take to travel point A to point B?

The center is not 0, 0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve, you'd need to now the angular displacement going from point $A$ to point $B$ on the circle of the radius you've been given.

Let the center of the circle be $C$.

There are a couple of ways to do this, but the easiest (IMO) is to draw a triangle $ABC$ connecting the three points $A,B,C$ and use the distance formula to find the length $|AB|$. Let this distance be $d$.

Note that $$|AC|=|BC|=R$$
since the segments |AC| and |BC| are from the center of the circle to points on the circle.

From this, apply the law of cosines to obtain your angle
$$d^2=R^2+R^2-2R^2\cos\Delta\theta\to \Delta\theta=\dots$$
Then use the angular kinematic equation to solve for the time:
$$\Delta \theta=\omega t +\frac{1}{2}\alpha t^2$$
I'm assuming that $\alpha=0$ (since you haven't given one in the problem), so then:
$$\Delta \theta=\omega t$$

Comment: Just some minor details: don't use two different notations ($theta$ and $\Delta\theta$) for the same thing, and $\alpha$ is not given, so you might assume constant angular velocity. Otherwise +1.

Comment: @Andrei Good suggestions! I edited my response.